# c# dialog script for unity game auto-typing issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a dialog script for my game, using some kind of autotyping style. The problem is when I start the game it gives me an error: *IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range*. After I fixed this I I lost the autotyping effect, the message just appears instantly.

```
using UnityEngine;    
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class texttype : MonoBehaviour {


    public float letterPause = 0.2f;
    //public AudioClip[] typeSound1;
    //public int next;
    string message;


    public GameObject textB;
    public Text text;
    public TextAsset textf;
    public string[] lines;
    public int currentLine;
    public int endline;


    void Start () {
        if (text == null) {
            text = GetComponent<Text> ();
        }
        message = text.text;
        StartCoroutine(TypeText ());

    if (textf != null) {

            lines = (textf.text.Split('\n'));
        }

    if (endline == 0) {

            endline = lines.Length - 1;
        }


    }

    IEnumerator TypeText () {

        foreach (char letter in message.ToCharArray()) {
            text.text += letter;
            yield return 0;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (letterPause);

        }
    }



    void Update () {

        text.text = lines [currentLine];

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {

            currentLine += 1;
        }
        if (currentLine > endline) {

            textB.SetActive(false);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through your MonoBehaviour, here's what I see it doing:

1. Set the `text` element if it is not already initialized
2. Copy the text content from `text` into the variable `message`
3. Start adding the content of `message` to the `text` component's value character by character
4. Read the `TextAsset` into a collection of strings, split per line
5. Set the total number of lines
6. On the `Update()` frame, set the text content of `text` to the string value of the current line
7. Check if the user has pressed the spacebar, and if so move the line index up by one
8. Check if the last line has been exceeded, and if so disable the game object

There are a few flow problems here. The biggest issue is the competition between your coroutine and the `Update()` tick. You probably want to move your call to start the coroutine into a separate function, and use a blocking variable to determine when you can or can't trigger the routine.

Consider the following:

```
// ignoring the using statements...

public class texttype : MonoBehaviour {


    public float letterPause = 0.2f;
    //public AudioClip[] typeSound1;
    //public int next;
    string message;


    public GameObject textB;
    public Text text;
    public TextAsset textf;
    public string[] lines;
    public int currentLine;
    public int endline;
    public bool isPrinting;


    void Start () {
        if (text == null) {
            text = GetComponent<Text> ();
        }

        // it's not clear where you store the full message, but I'm assuming inside textf
        // if you have it stored in message or text.text, then you can initialize it here

        if (textf != null) {
            lines = (textf.text.Split('\n'));
        }

        if (endline == 0) {
            endline = lines.Length - 1;
        }    
    }

    IEnumerator TypeText () {    
        // get current line of text
        string current = lines[currentLine];

        foreach (char letter in current.ToCharArray()) {
            text.text += letter;
            yield return 0; // not sure this line is necessary
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (letterPause);    
        }

        // unlock and wait for next keypress
        isPrinting = false;
    }



    void Update () {
        // if we're already printing a line, we can short-circuit
        if (isPrinting) return;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
            // move line index
            currentLine += 1;

            if (currentLine > endline) {    
                textB.SetActive(false);
                return;
            }

            // start printing
            PrintNext();
        }

    }

    void PrintNext() {
        // redundant check, but better safe than sorry
        if (isPrinting) return;

        // lock while printing
        isPrinting = true;

        StartCoroutine(TypeText ());      
    }

}
```